# SSH login too slow in Centos 6.6

Tags: sshd, vsftpd

SSH login take too much time in my CentOS machine, and also a ftp server is running on it.

Please help me to speedup the login time for both root and ftp user. I tried some tricks but no improvements.

Tries are shown below:

Already added some thinks into `cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config`

> GSSAPIAuthentication no
>
> UseDNS no

SSH login time is :

> real 0m18.950s
>
> user 0m0.022s
>
> sys 0m0.016s

Comment: What is the relevance of the ftp server to slow ssh logins, please?

Comment: Post the output of `ssh -vv yourserver`

Answer (score 1):

Did you restart the `ssh` service? Are two consecutive SSH logins (within a minute or two) both slow?

Perform `ssh -vvv user@host` from the client to see where it waits.

If that does not help, you might stop the SSH service (if you have other ways to access the host) and start SSH in the foreground with debugging on: `sshd -Dd`. Then try to make a SSH connection and see what the server is doing.